# Which ca.crt does docker.sock use for docker pull?

Tags: ssl, docker, docker-registry

When I do `docker pull` from inside a container that uses `/var/run/docker.sock` to run docker (docker inside docker), I got this error:

`` FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://registry.com:5000/v1/_ping: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry registry.com:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.com:5000/ca.crt ``

So I followed the instruction and added the `ca.crt` inside that directory and also added the insecure option to `/etc/default/docker`, but the error didn't go away.

I wonder where `/var/run/docker.sock` command look for the cert when I pull from inside the container. Especially when pulling works from outside (host) with the same config (ca.crt in the right folder and the insecure option is also added).

Comment: Off the top of my head, the pull should run from the dockerd daemon running on the host, not from the client side inside the container.

Comment: @BMitch so would it look for the cert folder (/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.com:5000/ca.crt) from the host as well?

Comment: Are you using the old v1 registry?  The ca.crt must contain the whole chain, starting from the subCA's up to the CA (if self-signed or unknown).  If it is a known CA (ca-certificates is installed, in the case of Debian based distros), you can omit it but it won't hurt being there.

Comment: @Casper I believe so, so I'm not seeing what step you're missing from the output you've shown. You may want to check the daemon logs on the host to see if anything is being flagged there.

Comment: @RicardoBranco I'm using v2, but as I mentioned, it works perfectly from the host with `ca.crt = domain.crt`, but when I'm inside the container, the pull command gave that error, which brings me to the question whether the pull command looks for the cert from inside container or from the host, both of these places have the same path to ca.crt

Comment: Is the **ca-certificates** (or equivalent in other distros) package installed?

Comment: @RicardoBranco Yeah it is installed, `ca-certificates.crt` is symlinked to `/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.com:5000/` in the host level as well.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run/docker.sock` is not the thing that is looking for a cert. That is simply the socket that you use to communicate with dockerd. When you do a pull, you are asking the docker daemon to go talk to a registry.

Where did you get the `ca.crt` file? Is that really the signing certificate for your `registry.com:5000` server's certificate? Did you put that in `/et c/default/docker/registry.com:5000/ca.crt` on the host where dockerd is running, or inside the container?

That `ca.crt` file belongs where the daemon is running. Double check that you have that correct file in the correct place on the host, and that should fix the issue.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the pull command works from the host level, I placed the ca.crt (domain.crt) in here `/etc/default/docker/registry.com:5000/ca.crt`. If the pull command is from the host level, how come it doesn't work inside the container but does work from outside? That's what confused me.

Comment: Are you talking to the same docker daemon from inside the container? Or, are you running something like dind?

Comment: Same docker daemon, there's also a docker installed inside the container but I'm not using that, docker.sock is being used here

Comment: How are you exposing docker.sock inside the container?

Comment: Honesly I'm not sure, probably something like this `docker container run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock portainer/portainer`

Comment: ah, that looks like you are indeed passing in the correct doctor.sock. If you look in the daemon's logs, do you see the error related to the tls?

Comment: No error related to TLS, but there's the same error with the cert that got printed after docker pull command.

Comment: It almost sounds like you have a typo or other discrepancy between the pull commander doing from inside the container and from somewhere else. The docker daemon does not care where the client connects from.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work now, the solution is to restart the docker daemon inside the container. I actually tried it before but the docker service kept going down after restart, that made me think it was the docker service from the host.

The reason I could not restart docker service is `/var/run/docker.pid` existed which prevent docker from starting again. So I deleted that pid and docker restarted successfully.